# Getting file names without file extensions with glob

Tags: python, glob

I'm searching for .txt files only

```
from glob import glob
result = glob('*.txt')

>> result
['text1.txt','text2.txt','text3.txt']
```

but I'd like `result` without the file extensions

```
>> result
['text1','text2','text3']
```

Is there a regex pattern that I can use with `glob` to exclude the file extensions from the output, or do I have to use a list comprehension on `result`?

Comment: Your title is a little misleading, would `Getting file names without file extension with glob` be better?

Comment: @Simon Agreed. The title as is sounds like it’s looking for libmagic or some other heuristic way to detect text files. And your rewrite sounds good to me.

Comment: @abarnert Should I edit it myself?  Without OP consent?

Comment: As a side note: `glob` doesn’t take regex patterns, it takes glob patterns, which are a different thing. Under the covers, it does build regex patterns to apply to a list of files, but you don’t get to see those. (If you want to see them, see the `fnmatch` module.)

Comment: @Simon I think that’s fine. The OP can always revert if they disagree, and if not, you’ve improved their question for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that with `glob()`, You need to take the list given and then create a new one to store the values without the extension:

```
import os
from glob import glob

[os.path.splitext(val)[0] for val in glob('*.txt')]
```

`os.path.splitext(val)` splits the file names into file names and extensions.  The `[0]` just returns the filenames.

Answer (score 3):

This glob only selects files without an extension: `**/*/!(*.*)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you’re trying to split off a filename extension, not split an arbitrary string, it makes more sense to use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) (or the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module). While it’s true that the it makes no *practical* difference on the only platforms that currently matter (Windows and *nix), it’s still conceptually clearer what you’re doing. (And if you later start using path-like objects instead of strings, it will continue to work unchanged, to boot.)

So:

```
paths = [os.path.splitext(path)[0] for path in paths]
```

---

Meanwhile, if this really offends you for some reason, what `glob` does under the covers is just calling `fnmatch` to turn your glob expression into a regular expression and then applying that to all of the filenames. So, you can replace it by just replacing the regex yourself and using capture groups:

```
rtxt = re.compile(r'(.*?)\.txt')
files = (rtxt.match(file) for file in os.listdir(dirpath))
files = [match.group(1) for match in files if match]
```

This way, you’re not doing a listcomp on top of the one that’s already in `glob`; you’re doing one *instead of* the one that’s already in `glob`. I’m not sure if that’s a useful win or not, but since you seem to be interested in eliminating a listcomp…

Comment: @abanert: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use index slicing:

```
result = [i[:-4] for i in result]
```

Comment: This works, but it’s not as clear or robust as using `splitext`, or even `rsplit`. If you later change the code to accept both `.txt` and `.text`, for example, the other solutions keep working, but this one doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> result = ['text1.txt','text2.txt.txt','text3.txt']
>>> [x.rsplit('.txt', 1)[0] for x in result]
['text1', 'text2.txt', 'text3']
```

You could do as a list-comprehension:

```
result = [x.rsplit(".txt", 1)[0] for x in glob('*.txt')]
```

Comment: Why not just `rsplit('.')`?

Comment: @abarnert sure that's working too. But I think its better use `.txt` as OP is specific about .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split`

```
>>> result = [r.split('.')[0] for r in glob('*.txt')]
>>> result
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

Comment: This will do the wrong thing for, say, `text.file.10.txt`, returning `text` instead of `text.file.10` (which would be correct on some obsolete platforms, but not on Windows or Unix).